# Получение превью из разных путей к картинке

Tags: android

В своем проекте я использую этот код для получения превьюшек:

```
Cursor cursor = crThumb.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID }, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "'", null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        thumbnailBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, cursor.getInt(0), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
    }
    cursor.close();
```

}

На моем устройстве к одному рисунку может вести два разных пути. Например, /storage/emulated/0/Download/dog.jpg и /mnt/sdcard/Download/dog.jpg указывают на один и тот же файл - dog.jpg. Код выше отлично работает для первого пути, но не работает для второго (cursor.getCount()==0). Как это обойти? Как получить превьюшку для второго пути?

**UPDATE**. А может быть есть возможность получить путь с которым работает галерея? Т.е., путь по которому она может отображать превью?

Comment: А почему Вы хотите получать доступ к картинке именно через Cursor?

Comment: Мне нужно получать превьюшки по полному пути к файлу. Другого способа я просто не нашел. Я что-то упустил и можно сделать как-то иначе?

Comment: Подписался на вопрос. Может быть тут напишут способ получения полного пути без использования Cursor.

Comment: Обратится к галерее. там будут все папки с картинками

Comment: А можете привести код, как именно обращаться к галерее? Как получить превью картинки имея путь к файлу?